# How to float and pin background elements in a responsive and scalable manner?

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, responsive-design

#### Context

I'm a much better back-end developer than I am a front-end one, which is why I suppose I'm having issues. For a new project, I've designed a layout as depicted below and I want to implement it in my React project - using CSS/SCSS.

This is the layout I'm looking to create:

[image]

It's meant to be the background of a page, and, indeed, the opacity of the rotated elements in the background and the gradient are all trivial to implement. What it comes down to, thus, is this:

[image]

#### Problem

The issue I'm having is that I'm unsure how to style those three rotated background elements in a manner that permits them to remain pinned to the edge of the screen, to be responsive, and to scale with changing screen sizes. I'm not sure if it's best to manually implement different sizes through media queries or if there's a one size fits all solution.

#### Attempted Solutions

1. I tried making the background elements be divs, and then I used the `transform: rotate() translateX() translateY()` property to move them. That works, but of course, it's coupled to a specific screen size. Once the screen is resized, those static `translate` values don't move, and thus, the elements go off the screen. Media queries could potentially be useful here, but I may need many of them.
2. I took the whole background from my design software and I made it into one single SVG. Then I applied that as the background with the following properties:

```css
body {
    background-image: url('path/to/img.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This also doesn't work, because it seems to crop the image when you reduce the screen size. For a large screen size, you have:

[image]

And for a small screen size:

[image]

I apologize if this is a bit of a stupid question. As I said, I'm not great when it comes to front-end design for I spend most of my time on the server. Thanks for your help/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the whole with only background:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
  /* left part*/                                                               /* position      / width height */
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.5%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%) left 0 top -80px / 80px 200px,
    linear-gradient(to top   left ,transparent 49.5%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%) left 0 top 120px / 80px 70px,
    /* right part*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%) right 0 top 20px / 80px 70px,
    linear-gradient(to top right   ,transparent 49.5%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%) right 0 top 90px / 80px 200px,
    /* bottom part*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 50%) bottom 0 left 20px / 200px 80px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49.5%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 50%) bottom 0 left 220px / 70px 80px,
    /* main background */
    linear-gradient(45deg,#5fd6df,#e23bf5);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Each gradient is a triangle shape and you simple use two triangle for each part that you resize and position like you want.

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. Thanks very much. I had no idea you could do that all in the same background. I'm going to fiddle with this for a bit to see if I can make it match my other layout exactly (and I'll probably look at the MDN Docs) and then I'll get back to you and accept your answer. Thanks again. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill to easily manage this, make a different color for each gradient so you can better see the puzzle. Then when you are done with sizing/positionning put the final colors

Comment: Thanks That's a good idea. If you don't mind, could you tell me what the `left 0 top -80px/80px 200px` portion after the closing parentheses of the linear gradient function does? I've never seen that syntax before (in terms of having direction/location information after the gradient). Thanks.

Comment: It also seems that having the transparency amount be 49.5 percent almost seems to emulate anti-aliasing. If I set the transparency to 50 percent instead, for example, the edges become grainy. The former smooths the edges out.

Comment: It works great. Thanks. I managed to get the values all sorted out to match my other layout: https://imgur.com/a/7zTBArE

I suppose now I could just set media queries too to further optimize for smaller or larger devices?

Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill `left 0 top -80px/80px 200px` --> means `position / dimension`. The slash separate the position of the gradient with the width and height of the gradient (this is the shorthand syntax. for the 49.5% yes it's for antialiasing because as you have noticed using 50 will give bad results